# CentOS 6 IPTables commands not responsive, firewall is down

Tags: centos, iptables

We have had this issue before but we thought it was due to installing CSF. This has now happend again where none of the commands for IPTables return anything. 'iptables -L' doesn't display anything, restarting doesn't bring it back to blinking prompt and just sits there at:

```
 /etc/init.d/iptables restart
 iptables: Applying firewall rules:
```

/etc/init.d/iptables -status returns

```
 iptables: Firewall modules are not loaded.
```

We have a firewall script that we have been using forever and we regularly edit with all of our rules in it and this also just freezes.

which iptables

```
 /sbin/iptables
```

Help is appreciated, I don't want to do a full re install of the server again.

Comment: Maybe a kernel update so that the modules in `/lib/modules` don't match the running kernel and you simply have to reboot?

Comment: last time we rebooted the server didn't boot again that's why we had to re install.

Comment: I am very sprry for you but servers have to be restarted. Period. Reinstalling the OS is really not the solution to boot problems. Understanding and getting rid of them is the solution. Just consider that the system may crash any time. Does your consideration for service inavailability contain the OS installation time? :-S I doubt that people on serverfault are interested in helping someone who refuses to patch and reboot his server...

Comment: @HaukeLaging There's plenty of valid reasons why an SA may not want to patch and/or reboot a server. Whether this particular OP has a valid reason or not, is a different matter. In any case, to the OP: you can get more clues if you "strace" or "gdb" on iptables when you restart it. That would be the first place I would start.

Comment: Just incase anyone else has this issue... if iptables says it is applying firewall rules, but then 'service iptables status' says "Firewall modules are not loaded", it is because /etc/sysconfig/iptables is an empty file. It doesn't bother loading the firewall modules since there is nothing for it to do (you have no rules defined).